# location.state fail with gatsby build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

When I use the `state` with the gatsby component `Link` that work when I do test with `gatsby develop` but failded with `gatsby build` with an error about `undefined` stuff. The error message show by the terminal is `WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined`  I try to check for `undefined` by two differents ways but that's don't work. I cannot figure what I must do to solve that's problem.
first test :

```
if (!location.state.info) {
    return null
} else
```

second test

```
if (typeof location.state.info === `undefined`) {
  return null
} else
```

index page

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Link to="/page_test/" state={{ info: "test" }}>
      Test
    </Link>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

page

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const TestPage = ({ location }) => {
  return <div>{location.state.info}</div>
}

export default TestPage
```

Comment: The error message implies that `location.state` is "undefined", not `location.state.info`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @str  thanks that's what you say, I don't test the good element :)  now that's work great.  For information I try to make an example very short... I cannot imagine a more simplest one !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's `undefined` is `location.state`, not the `info` state itself. Changing your condition your code should work.

```
if (typeof location.state === `undefined`) {}
```

Here's some approach (same idea) using destructuring:

```
const TestPage = ({ location }) => {
  const { state = {} } = location
  const { info } = state

  return info ? (
    <div>{info}</div>
  ) : (
    <div>Other content</div>
  )
}

export default TestPage
```

Basically, with the destructuring, you are simplifying stuff. It's what you are using in `({ location })`. By default, `props` are passed through pages and components in React so `({ location })` equals to `(props)` and then `props.location`. It's just a way of entering the nested properties of the object.

In the same way, once you have `props.location` (or `location` if destructured in `props`), you can:

```
 const { state = {} } = location //equals to location.state
```

In the case above, you are destructuring plus setting a default value to empty (`{}`) if there's no `state` nested object in `location`.

In the same way:

```
  const { info } = state //equals to state.info
```

If `state` is empty due to the previous destructuring, info will be empty as well, if not, it will take the value of `state.info`. So your return method can be a boolean condition such:

```
  return info ? (
    <div>{info}</div>
  ) : (
    <div>Other content</div>
  )
```

Comment: Like say @str I write the code like that and now that's work ```const TestPage = ({ location }) => {
  if (!location.state) {
    return null
  } else {
    return <div>{location.state.info}</div>
  }
}```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the same approach using destructuring instead ;)

Comment: whaouuu, javaScript, React and Gatsby is very huge to learn too many ways... the C++ or C is very simple by comparison !!!

Comment: Indeed!  I've updated the question adding some explanations. Hope it helps!